# Need help with bulkifying code

Tags: apex, bulkification

```
   global with sharing class LOYMemberServcies
 {
  public Map<Membership_card__C,Member__c> postMemberEnrollmentActivities(Map<String,Member__C> newMem)
{
    //Get the base tier
    system.debug('%%%'+newMem);
  Map<Membership_card__C,Member__c> mapCardMember = new Map<Membership_card__C,Member__c>();
  for(String ss : newMem.keyset()){
    //create new membership card
    Member__c updateMem = new Member__c();
    updateMem = newMem.get(ss);
          system.debug('%%%'+updateMem );
    Membership_card__C mc = new Membership_Card__C();
    mc.member__c = updateMem.Id;
    List<String> tierClass = ss.split(',');
    mc.card_type__C = tierClass[0];

    //udpate hte member record
      updateMem.tier__C = tierClass[1];
      //updateMem.membership_card__C = mc.id;
      mapCardMember.put(mc,updateMem);

  }
  return mapCardMember;
}

//Enroll the contact into a given program.
//If the contact id is present, then duplicate check will be done to ensure one contact is part of one program only once.

global static List<String> EnrollTheContactIntoProgram(List<Contact> con,String programName)
{
    List<String> result = new List<String>();
    Program__c program=[select id,Name from Program__c where name=:programName limit 1];
    List<Contact> newCon = new List<Contact>();
    Map<Id,Contact> existCon = new Map<Id,Contact>();
    List<Id> conId = new List<Id>();
    for(contact c : con){
      String contactId = c.Id;

    system.debug('***'+c);

    //check if contact id is null (new contact)
    if(contactId == null)
    {
        //create the new contact
        newCon.add(c);
        // then create a new member..   
        }
    else
    {
           conId.add(c.Id); //check the duplicate of hte contact.
           existCon.put(c.Id,c);
           system.debug('im in else'+existCon);
    }       
    }
    if(newCon.size()>0)
    {
     insert newCon;
}        

     List<Member__C> membersWithSameContact = [select id,Contact__c from Member__C where Contact__C IN :conId and Program__C = :program.ID LIMIT 1];
            //check if htere is atlest one membership for the contact in the same program
    system.debug('******'+membersWithSameContact);

 for(id i : existCon.keyset())
 {
    if(membersWithSameContact.size()>0)
    {
    for(Member__c m : membersWithSameContact)
      {

      if(existCon.get(m.Contact__c) != null )
            {
                result.add( ' The contact is already part of the same Program'+m.Id);
            }
            else
            {
                //create the new member for the existing contact.
                newCon.add(existCon.get(m.Contact__c) );
             }   
           }  
      }
      else
      {
       newCon.add(existCon.get(i) );
      }
      }   


 system.debug('****'+newCon);
    List<Member__c> newMem = new List<Member__c>();
    for(Contact cs : newCon){
    Member__c newMember = new Member__C();
    newMember.program__C = program.Id;
    newMember.Contact__C = cs.Id;
    newMember.Name = cs.Name;
    newMem.add(newMember);
    }                  
    insert newMem;
    for(Member__c m : newMem)
    {
        result.add('Contact Id '+m.Contact__C+' has been enrolled into the program. Member Number: '+m.Id);
    }        

    return result;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Though a little hard to tell because of the bad indenting, the `EnrollTheContactIntoProgram` method itself does not contain any bulkification mistakes that I can see.

Perhaps that method is being called many times from some other code? To address that problem you would need to change the method signature to accept e.g. a set of program names and then modify both the calling code and the `EnrollTheContactIntoProgram` implementation.

On this site you need to provide all the relevant information (with irrelevant detail stripped out) and its best to also show what you have attempted yourself to solve the problem.